# Not able to play 13Mb video file

Tags: video, video-editor, windows, video-quality

I have developed a video which approximates to 13 Mb.I try opening it with Windows media player or Nero.It tries to open but then the player automatically closes.

Format is .avi

What could be the possible reason.Is size the issue?

Comment: What is the resolution ? AVI can support arbitrary sized (dimension) video, but many codecs and players do not.

Answer (score 3):

Not enough info. Try getting a copy of the GSpot Codec Information program (google it) and report back here what it says about the file.

Size is almost certainly not the problem.

Comment: It is almost certainly to do with not having the correct codec.

Answer (score 1):

Best tool for this is [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en).
This tool is opensource and has nearly daily updates for features and bug fixes. It is an analyzer of media files. Have many levels of how deep it will report you about media file. While it is not checking the integrity of the whole media file it check correctness of headers and tells you about capabilities.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and explain why? I suspect you might be right but it's not clear whether this tool is helpful from your answer or the link.

Comment: This tool is opensource and have nearly daily update for features and bug fixes. It is analyzer of media files. Have many levels of how deep it will report you about media file. While it is not checking integrity of whole media file it check correctness of headers and tells you about capabilities.

Comment: @Whity You should add the contents of your comment into your answer - I suspect that would earn you some upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

Size should not be an issue.
You probably have a corrupt video file. This would explain why players close when trying to decode it.

You can try to preview the video with this tool:
http://mp4repair.org

(disclaimer: I'm affiliated with this website)